# Is there a way to restore or promote an older version of a secret?

Tags: azure-keyvault

I know you can restore deleted secrets, however, I want to delete the current version and restore an older version.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the **old** secret value then create a new version with it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is possible. However, you can try PowerShell to get the old version of the secret using the cmdlet `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret` with `-Version` parameter, store the returned secret in a variable, say `$oldsecret` and then use the `Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret` cmdlet to update the existing secret in Key Vault with the `$oldsecret`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do this.  All I can do is create a new secret, which I don't need.  the value didn't change, just the tags.  So I had to update our code to use the new version.  at least the old version was still enabled so nothing broke during the changes.

Answer (score 0):

One hack is to download the specific version that you want to be the current version and then set it in the KV using the `az cli`.

`az keyvault secret download --vault-name <vault-name> --name <secret-name> --version <secret-version> --file <output-file>`

`az keyvault secret set --vault-name <vault-name> --name <secret-name> --file <output-file>`

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not possible. An alternative is to take following steps using PowerShell:

1. Make sure Az module is installed on your local computer, if not run

   Install-Module Az
2. Get your secret:

   Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'vaultnumber' -Name 'secretname' -Version 'versionnumber' -AsPlainText | Out-File -FilePath .\Process.txt
3. edit your saved file, save and close it and read the file:

   $text = Get-Content -Path 'path' -Raw
4. Write it to the key vault

   $newSecret= ConvertTo-SecureString $text -AsPlainText -Force

   Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName vaultnumber -Name secretname -SecretValue $newSecret